# Migrating data from an Access database to an SQL database with a different structure and different table names

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have been trying to migrate data from an Access database(2016) to an SQL database with a different structure and different table names.

This is the structure Access database, but now in phpmyadmin :-
[image: img1]

I usually use phpmyadmin to create databases.
This is the structure of the tables of the database in phpmyadmin :-

[image: img2]

I am wondering if it is possible to migrate the data and if that is so why I am getting this error while trying to migrate the data.

> Jun 28, 2016 2:29:13 PM
>   com.intellisoftkenya.onetooner.gui.MainFrame$MigrationWorker
>   doInBackground INFO: Process started. Jun 28, 2016 2:29:13 PM
>   com.intellisoftkenya.onetooner.gui.MainFrame$MigrationWorker
>   doInBackground SEVERE: An error occured while migrating data from
>   'tblCurrentStatus' to 'patient_status'. Jun 28, 2016 2:29:13 PM
>   com.intellisoftkenya.onetooner.gui.MainFrame$MigrationWorker
>   doInBackground INFO: Attempting to delete any inconsistent data from
>   'patient_status'. Jun 28, 2016 2:29:13 PM
>   com.intellisoftkenya.onetooner.gui.MainFrame$MigrationWorker
>   doInBackground INFO: Deleted 0 records from 'patient_status'. Fix the
>   errors and re-run the process. Jun 28, 2016 2:29:13 PM
>   com.intellisoftkenya.onetooner.gui.MainFrame$MigrationWorker
>   doInBackground SEVERE: Migration error!.
>   com.intellisoftkenya.onetooner.business.MigrationException: Process
>   aborted! See logs for details.

I am able to clear the destination successfully using the migrating tool; meaning the migration tool is able to communicate with my database.

Comment: **Did you** ___See logs for details___ If not then do, and if you did maybe you could add that information for us to see

Comment: I saw the logs and I already uploaded most of the information on it

Comment: What tool are you using to convert between Access and MySQL? phpMyAdmin doesn't speak to Access at all, and Access's syntax is not directly compatible with MySQL SQL.